# Code prints out only first item searched instead of all of them

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the entire code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

search_item = ["Sony Camera"]

def all_links(names):
    url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1312.R1.TR11.TRC2.A0.H0.XIp.TRS1&_nkw="
    urls = []
    for name in names:
             urls.append(url + name.replace(" ", "+"))
    return urls

def display_results(urls):
    for url in urls:
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        name = soup.findAll("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"}).get_text(separator=u" ")
        price = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "s-item__price"}).get_text()

        print("Item Name: " + name + "\n")
        print("Price: " + price + "\n")

display_results(all_links(search_item))
```

Not sure why am I getting only first item found printed out. The lines code for name and price must be culprit. Thanks

Comment: What do you think that `[0]` in those two lines is doing?

Comment: Without [0] I get nothing but errors. With it at least I get first product displayed in the page. How do I get it do display from [0 to all]?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly, as of now, this is not a valid Python code.

Comment: Have  you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop thru the `.find_all()` to get all the items, because now, you're only getting the first result only with the `[0]`.

By the way, indentation in Python is crucial. Typically, `4 spaces` are used, not `6` as in your example. And you have an unused import `lxml`.

Here's how:

```
import locale

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1312.R1.TR11.TRC2.A0.H0.XIp.TRS1&_nkw="
search_item = ["Sony Camera"]

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")


def all_links(names):
    return [f"{base_url}{name.replace(' ', '+')}" for name in names]


def display_results(urls):
    for url in urls:
        res = requests.get(url)
        res.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        names = [
            i.getText(strip=True) for i
            in soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"})
        ]
        prices = [
            i.getText(strip=True).replace("$", "") for i
            in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
        ]

        prices = [locale.atof(p) for p in prices]
        product_data = sorted(zip(names, prices), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)

        for product_info in product_data:
            product_name, product_price = product_info
            print(f"Item Name: {product_name}\nPrice: {product_price}")


display_results(all_links(search_item))
```

Output:

```
Item Name: New ListingSony a7 III 24.2 MP Mirrorless Digital Camera - Black (Body Only)
Price: 1450.0
Item Name: Sony Cyber-shot RX10 IV 20.2 MP Digital Camera DSC-RX10 IV Kit
Price: 1275.0
Item Name: Sony Alpha a6400 Mirrorless Camera
Price: 950.0
Item Name: Sony Alpha A7 Full Frame Mirrorless Camera
Price: 800.0
Item Name: [RARE! UNUSED in BOX] Sony SLT-A65VX  24.3MP DSLR Camera Double Lens Kit From JP
Price: 799.99

and so on...
```

Comment: soup.find_all( ) it gives me error in console ResultSet object has not attribute get.text. How do I use soup_find_all then?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either with `find_all()` or `findAll()`. Can you show the full error tracestack?

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: the error is with [0] removed from both code lines. With it I get only first using find_all

Comment: In my answer it's `getText()` not `get_text()` please double check. And try running the code I've posted in the answer.

Comment: Could you copy paste my answer as is and run it? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: If you can take a second look at the code you have provided it's taking the prices from somewhere else. I've been looking through the code and I can't pick where the mistake lies.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "it's taking the prices from somewhere else". I've checked the output and it matches the price with the right listing. Albeit, it's not sorted. I've added sorting to the code.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please up-vote and/or accept it.

Comment: If I change search_item with anything else I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: ’75.00to775.00’. please take a look. thanks

Comment: The error lies in the locale expression, by the way. If you know how to fix it please do that. thanks

Comment: I know how to fix this but I won't. I'm done with this answer. Happy coding!